# How to count service workers in Chrome & Firefox?

Tags: userscripts

I think service workers are starting to be used more as a ploy to circumvent ad blockers via desktop notifications, and they are bloating web browsers the way tool bars used to.  I'd like an easy way to count them with something like Tampermonkey or Developer tools, but Tampermonkey won't run on local pages like

```
chrome://serviceworker-internals/
```

and

```
about:serviceworkers
```

in Chrome and Firefox respectively.  What is the easiest way to count the number of service workers in a browser via software?  I'm often seeing more than I can easily count by hand on systems I help people with.